# Perform Azure Storage operations from VHD within same Storage account

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-virtual-machine

When working with a VHD hosted within an Azure Storage account, are there any operations one can perform to access the Storage account directly?

I.e. I create a VM and store it's VHD in a blob in account A, are there any local/efficient ways to work with data in account A from the VM?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. Are you asking if you can access files within a vhd directly (without a vm attached to it), or asking if you can access other blobs in a storage account where a vhd resides? Please edit your question to clarify.

Answer (score -1):

See if [Azure Storage Files service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-files/) will work for you. You may attach your storage as a file share and communicate with that directly using traditional APIs.

Apart of that, you may use cross-platform [Azure Storage Explorer](http://storageexplorer.com) for communicating with other Storage subservices like Blobs.